# Multiple Questions on Fancybox 2: Multi-image from One link, Video and Images in same gallery, How to prevent cycle

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm going to ask multiple questions in this one message if that's okay. I've searched for answers for each independently but at this point I think it's all just a bit over my head so apologies for the basic questions. I'm a designer and a terrible coder, but I can't find a theme that has everything that I want.

I'm trying to create a portfolio page that will have multiple items (styled text, images, video) from one link. There will also be multiple links for different galleries. I've looked over the examples page from the Fancybox site and I got *something* to work for images, but I feel like it's probably incredibly kludgy and wrong.

The structure I would like is as follow:

Company 1 logo as link to gallery -> (text from to describe the work, image 1, image 2, image 3, mp4 file)

Company 2 logo as link to gallery -> (text from to describe the work, image 1, image 2, image 3, mp4 file)
etc.

What I've done so far based on the fancy box example is create an id for each gallery and then put a section of code for each client. Here's what I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <meta name="author" content="Jeffrey Nee" >
    <meta name="description" content="Jeffrey Nee Portfolio Site" >
    <meta name="keywords" content="Jeffrey Nee, Jeff Nee, Art Director, Creative Director, Los Angeles, San Francisco, Advertising, Microsoft, Carl's Jr." >
    <title>Jeffrey Nee | Art Director / Creative Director</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

</head>

<body id="body" >
<div id="content" >
<div id="header" ><a href="index.html" target="" name="" ><img src="images/neebook_straight.png" alt="" ></a><div id="nav" ><a href="index.html" target="" name="" >home </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;portfolio &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="about.html" target="" name="" >about </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="contact.html" target="" name="" >contact</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="miscellania.html" target="" name="" >miscellania</a></div></div>

<div id="portfolio_grid" ><div>

<a id="fancybox_BooksForDummies" href="javascript:;">Books For Dummies</a>
<a id="fancybox_BootCamp" href="javascript:;">Boot Camp</a>
<a id="fancybox_CHM" href="javascript:;">Computer History Museum</a>
<a id="fancybox_Encarta" href="javascript:;">Microsoft Encarta</a>
<a id="fancybox_Marketplace" href="javascript:;">Marketplace</a>
<a id="fancybox_OfficeMac" href="javascript:;">Office for Mac</a>
<a id="fancybox_OfficeXP" href="javascript:;">Office XP</a>
<a id="fancybox_Piaggio" href="javascript:;">Piaggio MP3</a>
<a id="fancybox_Rosemount" href="javascript:;">Rosemount</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
            *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
            */

            $('.fancybox-media')
                .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                .fancybox({
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    arrows : true,
                    helpers : {
                        media : {},
                        buttons : {}
                    }
                });

            /*
             *  Galleries
             */

            $("#fancybox_BootCamp").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : 'images/Print/Boot_Camp_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Boot_Camp_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Boot_Camp_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_BooksForDummies").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : 'images/Print/Books_for_Dummies.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_CHM").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : 'images/Print/Computer_History_Museum.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_Encarta").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Encarta_Office_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Encarta_Office_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Encarta_Office_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_Marketplace").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Marketplace_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Marketplace_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Marketplace_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_OfficeMac").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_Mac_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_Mac_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_Mac_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_OfficeXP").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_XP_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_XP_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Office_XP_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_Piaggio").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Piaggio_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Piaggio_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Piaggio_03.jpg'
                    }
                ], {

                });
            });

            $("#fancybox_Rosemount").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                                {
                        href : 'images/Print/Rosemount_01.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Rosemount_02.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Rosemount_03.jpg',
                    }, {
                        href : 'images/Print/Rosemount_04.jpg'
                    }
                    ], {
                });
            });

});
</script>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</body></html>
```

Now, I'm sure this is crap, but I can't suss out how to fix it and it is working right now for images.

Here's what I can't figure out:

• How to structure the galleries properly because I'm pretty sure this isn't right. I feel like the galleries should be a class somehow that just calls upon different data sets rather than separate instances.

• How to include a video file that's not hosted on a video service but just stored on my web server.

• How to create a page of just styled text that I can write a small summary of each gallery.

• How to have the transitions fade rather than this flipping from the top thing that doesn't animate well with such large files.

• How to stop the next and previous button from cycling through again. I was the first slide to have no back button and the last to have no forward button. Right now it just keeps cycling through and I think it would be confusing for my purposes.

Here's a link of what I have now that does seem to work with images other than the transition and cycling issues. I've also gotten it to work with an image as a link as well but I don't really need help with that.

[Portfolio Page](http://www.jeffnee.com/testing/portfolio.html)

Thanks to anyone who can help. I keep trying to learn this stuff and have just come the conclusion that perhaps my brain isn't wired to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you will need multiple answers (although you can accept only one). I will try some of them from the top of my head so,

**Q**: How to include a video file that's not hosted on a video service but just stored on my web server?

**A**: You need a player in any case. You may use *jwplayer* for instance.
Link your (flv, mp4, mpg) video directly like

```
<a class="myVideo" href="pathToVideo/video.flv">open my video in fancybox</a>
```

then use a script for such video like

```
 $("a.myVideo").click(function() {
   $.fancybox({
    'content': '<embed src="pathToPlayer/jwplayer.swf?file='+this.href+'&amp;autostart=true&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="352" height="240" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></embed>'               
   }); // fancybox
   return false;
  }); // click
```

**Q**: How to stop the next and previous button from cycling through again. I want the first slide to have no back button and the last to have no forward button.

**A**: set option `loop` to `false` like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 loop: false
});
```

**Q**: How to have the transitions fade rather than this flipping from the top thing that doesn't animate well with such large files?

**A**: Use these options

```
  openEffect: 'fade',
  prevEffect: 'fade',
  nextEffect: 'fade'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response JFK. I noodled around with it long enough to sort of get it going right. Mostly with the help of my cousin, who is a coder who can at least read the syntax. For the record I decided just to upload the videos to Vimeo and embedded them into an iframe to ensure that the player can play anywhere. The video I had is all SD stuff anyway, so the different in quality from the encoding is pretty minimal.
Thanks for your time.